# How can I make my dynamic table create new rows when I input into a form? Right now it creates the row but it creates a new one on every click

Tags: jquery

hello this is my current function

```
     <script>


  $(document).one('click', 'input.tr_clone_add', function() {
    var $tr    = $(this).closest('.tr_clone');
    var $clone = $tr.clone();
    $clone.find(':text').val('');
    $tr.after($clone);
});
    </script>
</head>
```

this is the html

```
<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Location</td>
        <td>From</td>
        <td>To</td>
        <td>Add</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr_clone">
        <td><input type="text" autofocus placeholder="who" name="add[]" class="tr_clone_add" ></td>
        <td><input type="text" autofocus placeholder="location" name="location" ></td>
        <td><input type="text" placeholder="Start Date" name="datepicker_start" class="datepicker"></td>
        <td><input type="text" placeholder="End Date" name="datepicker_end" class="datepicker"></td>

    </tr>

</table>
</body>
```

I want it to create a new row when I enter data into the first field of the table. It does do that but every letter  I press creates a new row. How do I stop this?

Comment: Please include the HTML code that is relevant as well as what you have attempted and/or figured out with regards to a solution.   https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: sorry I added the htm in

Comment: Well, now you are attaching a click event to the document that runs only once.   So the first time the user clicks anywhere on the page, it will run, then never run again.  no bueno.

Comment: Yes but when it's set to on instead of one it makes a new row every click and that's also bad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**

OK, so i made a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/69dqz270/1/) and got this solved.

1. added a data attribute to the TR element (`data-cloned="false"`) to keep track of which rows had already been cloned (so only clicking the newest row will create another clone)
2. placed the click event on the document, and used event delegation.  This allows us to fire the click event on dynamically added rows.
3. added a [0] index to this assignment to store the markup in our variable.  `var thisRow = $(this).closest('.tr_clone')[0];`

So basically, we create the thisRow variable and assign it the markup for our "clicked" row.

We then use `.data()` to check if the row has already been cloned.

If it has, we do nothing.

If it hasn't, we `.clone()` thisRow and chain `.insertAfter(thisRow)` and then chain the find/remove for the input values (`.find('input:text').val('');`)

Finally we use .data() to indicate that thisRow has been cloned already...
`$(thisRow).data("cloned", "true");`

---

**Answer**

First, [.live()](https://api.jquery.com/live/) is removed as of jQuery 1.9 so unless you are working with an ancient codebase you are going to want to check out [.on()](https://api.jquery.com/on/).

Second, you are attaching a [keydown](https://api.jquery.com/keydown/) event, so every time a key is pressed it will run the corresponding handler.  You will need to create logic in your event handler to keep track.   Personally, I would use a `click` event instead of keydown but it probably doesn't matter too much.

```
    (function($) {
    $(function() { //document.ready

        $(document).on('click', '.tr_clone_add', function() {

            var thisRow = $(this).closest('.tr_clone')[0];

            if (!$(thisRow).data("cloned")) {

                $(thisRow).clone()
                .insertAfter(thisRow)
                .find('input:text').val('');

                $(thisRow).data("cloned", "true");

            }
        });

    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: yes I just changed it to a newer jquery library and am now using the on function. Thanks for your reply I will play around with it!

Comment: Great!  Good luck and let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: wouldn't using that if statement be the same thing as changing the event handler to one or no? The problem is then only one new row is created and it stops there.

Comment: @JimCzerniak No, the if statement in combination with .on() is what I'm using here.  The if statement checks if the row that was clicked has been cloned already or not.   I'll expand my answer to explain how that works.

Comment: @JimCzerniak ... and BOOM goes the dynamite  (answer updated)  :)

Answer (score 1):

```
            $(document).on('input', 'input.tr_clone_add', function() {
            if(document.getElementById("dynamictable").tBodies[0].rows.length == 
                    (this.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex + 1)) {                         
                        var $tr    = $(this).closest('.tr_clone');
                        var $clone = $tr.clone();
                        $clone.find(':text').val('');
                        $tr.after($clone);
                }                                                                        
            });
```

This is what I came up with counted the rows and compared it to the event handler row and only allow it to run on the last row.

Answer (score 0):

thats because you fire your function everytime a "keydown" event happens, you have to use a debounce function for just execute the function when the last "keydown" event happens X milliseconds ago.

```
$("input").on('keydown', debounce(function(e) {
    console.log("It works!");
}, 250));

function debounce(func, wait, immediate) {
  var timeout;

  return function executedFunction() {
    var context = this;
    var args = arguments;

    var later = function() {
      timeout = null;
      if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
    };

    var callNow = immediate && !timeout;

    clearTimeout(timeout);

    timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);

    if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
  };
};
```

You can also use the debounce libary for jQuery, https://github.com/cowboy/jquery-throttle-debounce but if you only want to use a debounce i dont recommend it, because its much much more in the libary than only this.

working js fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ewm9ovLa/1/

credit David Walsh for the debounce function.

debounce function from here if you want to understand what happens there exactly: https://levelup.gitconnected.com/debounce-in-javascript-improve-your-applications-performance-5b01855e086